# Getting error when using bump with a target

Tags: anchor, pda, program, bump

fairly new to Solana/anchor dev here. When i `anchor build` i get this error:
`thread 'main' panicked at 'Code not parseable: Error("bump targets should not be provided with init. Please use bump without a target.")`

I'm currently initializing accounts with the macro:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(quantity: u64, vault_bump: u8)]
pub struct Withdraw<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        has_one = authority,
        constraint = margin_account.load()?.main_account == main_account.key(),
    )]
    pub margin_account: Loader<'info, MarginAccount>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"main-signer", main_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump = main_account.load()?.signer_bump,
    )]
    pub main_signer: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub main_account: Loader<'info, MainAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"token-account", main_account.key().as_ref(), from.mint.as_ref()],
        bump = vault_bump,
        constraint = from.mint == to.mint,
    )]
    pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub clock: Sysvar<'info, Clock>,
}
```

And i see on discord channels this is mentioned:
[image]
But in a bunch of other materials i see `bump` needs to be instantiated with some variable in order to find the PDA to be used later.
https://www.brianfriel.xyz/understanding-program-derived-addresses/
Pretty confusing and wondering whether it's some deprecated version and newer anchor versions don't require specifying the `bump` variable

Comment: Kindly include the complete Accounts struct. The error message suggests that the issue is not from the code you've included here.

Comment: Added the entire struct above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

> bump = main_account.load()?.signer_bump

, with `bump = bump`. Anchor derives the pda with this.

Comment: Do i ever need to include a `signer_bump or vault_bump` in the function params at all then? does anchor now abstract away all of these bumps?

Comment: Anchor does it for you. If you want to know your specific bump, use the following method in your code <<let (pda, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"PDA", ctx.accounts.user.key().as_ref()], &Pubkey::from_str("Ca8tecWTapYzeGfa8FvAMSo6JCheTRPvQhsjebZm56YE").unwrap());>> and save it in a variable